# What's the Command to purge/delete all contents in all "public_html" folders?

Tags: linux, centos, command, public-html

What's the Command in CentOS to purge/delete all contents in ALL "public_html" folders for all users at once?  (I have my web server that I just cloned to make it into a mail server, but I don't want too keep all the public_html files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if all the files are under `/home` and you want to remove all the contents of `/home/*/public_html` you could do

```
rm -rf /home/*/public_html/*
```